# std::set support in java swig

Tags: java, c++, swig, c++03

In my java code, I would like to call `std::set` default constructor and an insert e.g. the following code in C++ :

```
struct foo;
foo bar();
std::set<foo> toto;
toto.insert(b);
```

Swig [provides support for various STL containers for java](https://github.com/swig/swig/tree/master/Lib/java) such as `std::vector`, `std::string`, `std::map`... However there is no support for `std::set`.

So I found this [solution](https://chadretz.wordpress.com/2009/11/27/stl-collections-with-java-and-swig/) which involve a C++ wrapper and a java wrapper. I have not tried it yet, I am not sure it will work and I do not find it convenient.

Can we do better by proposing a minimal swig interface which handle a basic set constructor and insertion ?

For example an interface std_set.i like :

```
%{
#include <set>
#include <pair>
#include <stdexcept>
%}
namespace std {
template<class T> class set {
public:
  typedef T value_type;
  set();
  pair<iterator,bool> insert(const value_type& val); // iterator might be the difficulty here
}
```

Or create wrappers for a specific template instantiation :

```
%rename(SetFoo) std::set<foo>;
class std::set<foo> {
public:
    set();
    std::pair<std::set<foo>::iterator,bool> insert(const &foo val); // std::set<foo>::iterator not known here...
};
```

In both cases, I am stuck with this iterator issue and cannot come with a "simple" solution.

I have tried to play with [swig/Lib/std](https://github.com/swig/swig/tree/master/Lib/std) also without success for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to drop the iterator and came up with a simple wrapper header for my need :

```
#include <set>

template<typename T>
struct SetWrapper {
    SetWrapper() : data() {};
    void insert(const T& val) { data.insert(val); }
    std::set<T> data;
};
```

Then in the interface we can instantiate different versions of the template :

```
%template(SetFoo) SetWrapper<Foo>;
```

I had to take care about methods which have a `std::set` in parameters I had to extend a class such as the following :

```
struct A {
  A(const std::set& s); // this cannot be used directly unfortunately
}

%extend A {
  A(const SetWrapper& s) { // need a constructor with SetWrapper
    A *p = new A(s.data); // reuse the constructor above
    return p;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you still interested in "better" solutions?